# Is it possible to show a confirm dialog when 'Rebuild' is clicked on?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, contextmenu, rebuild

If so, how?

I keep on accidentally clicking on 'Rebuild' instead of 'Build' because they are right next to eachother.
I want a messagebox to show something like "Are you sure you want to rebuild this solution?", cancel the event if the user clicks on 'No' and proceed if 'Yes' is clicked.

Is there anyway at all to modify the context menu source code?

Comment: Perhaps you could write an Add-On

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963640/can-visual-studio-2010-prompt-before-rebuilding

Comment: Do you need to use Rebuild very often?  The menu structures are customisable, you can move it out of the way somewhere

Comment: You could take your time when clicking the build button

Comment: Or just hit ctrl-break/ctrl-c when you find out you hit the wrong button to minimize the damage. OR learn the shortcut key and never use the menu again.